# converting FOR loop to apply in R

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to learn how to use apply, but am getting a bit stuck.  This loop is converting all of the columns (except the first four) to their accumulated sums.

Can anyone help me?  Thanks!

```
for (i in seq_along(newbuilds.byfuel.bydate)) {
  if (i >= 5) {
    newbuilds.byfuel.bydate[i] <- cumsum(newbuilds.byfuel.bydate[i])

  }
}
```

Comment: Is `newbuilds.byfuel.bydate` a data.frame? Make sure to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when asking for help. That will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do this if your object is a `data.frame`:

```
## dummy dataset
x <- mtcars
```

Use `lapply` to loop over the desired columns, calculate the `cumsum`, and then overwrite the original columns:

```
x[5:ncol(x)] <- lapply(x[5:ncol(x)], cumsum)
```

Alternatively, loop over the un-dropped columns:

```
x[-(1:4)] <- lapply(x[-(1:4)], cumsum)
```

Comment: To avoid typing the col indices twice, I'd either define it as a separate variable or do something weird like `do.call(transform, c(list(x), lapply(x[-(1:4)], cumsum)))`

Comment: Looks like this works as well: `transform(x, lapply(x[-(1:4)], cumsum))`

Comment: That seems to have no effect on the cols..?

Comment: You're right. I made a rookie mistake by not rerunning my entire script.